# nusoap XML error parsing WSDL

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

im using nusoap to call an ASP.NET method that looks like (calling the method in .NET)

```
Dim obj As New ct400.WSConnector
objWS.someMethod ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","g");
```

(other than that i have no more documentation regarding this webservice method.)

this is the code im using to call the method with PHP

```
  $uri="192.x.x.x/somefolder/somefile.asmx;
  $client = new nusoap_client ($uri,true);
  $param = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g");
  $response = $client->call('methodname', $param);
```

the server should respond with simple "data is saved" "data was not saved"

when dumping the response im getting nothing.
when dumping the error ($client->getError())
im getting that annoying unhelpful message :-)

> XML error parsing WSDL from http://192.x.x.x/somefolder/somefile.asmx
>   on line 75: Mismatched tag

what am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the array parameter like this:

```
$params = array('P1'  => $val1,'P2'=> $val2);
//and call it like this in order to get .net understand your request (only for nusoap)
$result =$client->call('yourwsmethod', array('parameters' => $params)); 
var_dump($result);
```